# ideas on how to prove this statement about the Gram points?

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta, lambert-w

Let
\begin{equation}
  g (n) = 2 \pi e^{1 + W \left( \frac{8 n + 1}{8 e} \right)}
\end{equation}
be the approximate value of the $n$-th Gram point where W is the Lambert W function . Now define
\begin{equation}
  G (n) = \frac{Z (g (n))}{| Z (g (n)) |} + \frac{Z (g (n + 1))}{| Z (g (n +
  1)) |}
\end{equation} where Z is the Hardy Z function
then the function defined by
\begin{equation}
  B (n) = \frac{1}{4} G (n - 1) G (n)
\end{equation}
takes on the value $1$ when $n$ is a 'bad' Gram point for which $(- 1)^{n +
1} Z (g (n)) > 0$ and the value $0$ when it is a 'good' Gram point $(- 1)^{n
+ 1} Z (g (n)) < 0$.

Comment: Where did this come from?

Comment: Me myself and I. Why does that matter?